# How to increase max_upload_size on apache server

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, server

In my application, I want to upload a file more than 500 MB, but it's giving me an error as the file is too big to upload.

I tried different ways to increase max_upload_size in php.ini and through .htacccess

but its increased till 128MB not more than that.

is there any way to increase it more than 500MB

Thanks in advance

Comment: answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184513/change-the-maximum-upload-file-size

Comment: In the php.ini file

Answer (score 2):

To upload large files, post_max_size value must be larger than upload_max_filesize.

memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size

memory_limit > post_max_size > upload_max_filesize

PHP Default: 128M > 8M > 2M

So you can try to increase memory_limit as well if you've increased post_max_size and upload_max_filesize

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before

I tried this plugin to increase it 
 https://wordpress.org/plugins/upload-max-file-size/

and [image]

if it's not working  you can edit in the htaccess file in WordPress directory and edit the file replacing **xx** with your preferred value

```
php_value upload_max_filesize xxM
```